# Model showing wrong texture through UV map

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to fix a specific plane on my game rip to show the correct textures, and it's showing the textures from a completely different material on it instead of the correct one.
Here is the type of texture my plane should have:
[image]

This is what it has instead, the base colours for the entire model:

[image]

I'm trying to allocate those diamonds to the texture on the top left:
[image]

Additionally, this is the texture that the diamonds are pulling from:
[image]

Those orange dots correspond to those diamonds. I haven't changed anything, this is just what they're like on this model. I have tried scaling them and they won't budge at all. My concern is that since i can't change the scale on these, i will have to recreate the object and redo that specific portion.
Here's my .blend file, it should be all ready to go. Let me know if theres any problems accessing it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kQKbtxACUisM9jhOEXRpPyAK6VsucmBc/view?usp=drive_link